# Upload more than one media files with a post

Tags: uploads, media

I am not sure if this has been  asked to community before. I 'd like to have more than one upload  custom fields with WP post.

Could anyone please suggest if there is any plugin available for it OR if I can achieve it by using WordPress native feature.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "upload custom fields"?

Comment: Sorry I mean custom field from which file/media can be uploaded.

Comment: Ok. There's no native feature but you could either write your own metabox or look at any of the metabox plugins (Advanced Custom Fields and Metabox both spring to mind) for a slightly more pre-fabricated solution.